# Are split exact sequences exact in the opposite direction?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, exact-sequence

In an abelian category, let
$$0\longrightarrow A \overset{f}{\longrightarrow}B\overset{g}{\longrightarrow}C\longrightarrow0$$
be a split short exact sequence with $\ell f=1_A,gr=1_C$.
Is the sequence
$$0\longrightarrow C \overset{r}{\longrightarrow}B\overset{\ell}{\longrightarrow}A\longrightarrow0$$ also short exact? How can I prove this? Is this also true in $\mathsf{Grp}$?

Lastly, I proved $\operatorname{Im}f\cong A$, but didn't manage to prove $\operatorname{Ker}\ell \cong C$. I'd appreciate some help!

Comment: I think the second sequence might not even exist. For instance, let $B = A \oplus C$, and let $f$ and $g$ be the canonical inclusion and projection, respectively. Let $\ell$ be the canonical projection. Now, assume that $A = C$, and let $r$ be the injection $x \mapsto \left(x,x\right)$. Then, $\ell\circ r\neq 0$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg thanks for the counterexample! What about $\operatorname{Ker}\ell \cong C$?

Comment: If you have the first short exact sequence and $\ell f = 1_A$, then you can choose $r$ in such a way $gr= 1_C$ and the second sequence is short exact. This is Proposition 2.68 "Splitting maps" of [Abelian Categories](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/3/tr3abs.html) by P. Freyd.

Comment: @AndreaGagna how does your answer settle with Darij Grinberg's answer? Also, The proposition you mention appears in a very different form.. Could you post a more detailed answer?

Comment: @darijgrinberg but in your example $r$ is not a part of a biproduct diagram. If we take $f,g,r,\ell$ to be a biproduct diagram, then is the sequence $(r,\ell)$ exact?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by a biproduct diagram. Andrea ' s answer settles with mine because he just says that, for every $\ell $ there exists *some* $r $ for which the sequence is exact (but not that *every* right inverse of $g $ does the trick).

Comment: @Exterior If $f, g, r, \ell$ form a biproduct diagram (what Freyd calls direct sum system, see §2.4), then $(r, \ell)$ is exact basically by definition. Freyd's Proposition 2.42 is actually a necessary condition, as well; thus in order for our four morphisms to be a biproduct diagram, we need both the sequences of the OP to be exact. Furthermore, Proposition 2.68 tells us that for a given $\ell$ there exists $r$ such that these give rise to a biproduct diagram; moreover, as $r$ must be the kernel of $\ell$, this is uniquely determined up to automorphism of $C$.