# Short exact sequence is split iff contractible

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories, exact-sequence

Let $0\rightarrow A\overset{f}{\rightarrow} B \overset{g}{\rightarrow} C\rightarrow 0$ be a short exact sequence in an abelian category. I am trying to prove this SES is contractible iff it is split.
I managed the $\implies$ direction but I am having trouble with the converse.
First, the diagram:

[image]

The chain homotopy relations in the left and right diamonds are respectively $s_n\circ f+0\circ s_{n+1}=1_A$ and $s_{n+2}\circ 0+g\circ s_{n-1}=1_C$. By assumption, the sequence is split, so we can (and must) take $s_n$ to be the left inverse of $f$ and $s_{n-1}$ to be the right inverse of $g$. But now, in the middle diamond we are left with the relation $s_{n-1}g+fs_n=1_{A\oplus C}$. I can't seem to show why this arrow must be the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}$I think you mixed up the indices a bit. What you need to prove is that $f \circ s_n + s_{n-1} \circ g = \id_{A \oplus C}$. For simplicity I will go back to $B = A \oplus C$ for the middle term, and I will denote $r = s_n$, $s = s_{n-1}$. We have $r \circ f = \id_A$ and $g \circ s = \id_C$.

So we want to be that $\id_B = fr + sg$. Consider $\varphi = \id_B - sg$; then $g\varphi = g - gsg = g - g = 0_B$. Thus by exactness $\varphi$ factorizes through $A$ (by definition of the kernel), say $\varphi = fh$ for some $h : B \to A$. Then $fr\varphi = frfh = fh = \varphi$. Given the expression of $\varphi$, this translates to:
$$\begin{align}
& fr - frsg = \id_B - sg \\
\iff & \id_B = fr + sg - frsg.
\end{align}$$
So we're left with proving that $frsg = 0 \iff rsg = 0$ (because $f$ is monic). We thus have to prove that $rs = 0$ (since $g$ is epic).

But now this is because of how you *constructed* the (left/right) inverses of $f$ and $g$. Typically you start with either $r$ or $s$, and you construct the other out of it (by following the procedure described [there](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+exact+sequence) for example); and if you follow this procedure, you'll see that it will satisfy $r \circ s = 0$. Another way to see this is that, to write $B = A \oplus C$, you implicitly assume that the left inverse of $f$ is the projection $A \oplus C \to A$ and the right inverse of $g$ is the injective $C \to A \oplus C$; it's clear that the composition of these two maps is zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will correct the relation I wish to prove in the post. I am, however, working in an abelian category, so I don't want to work with elements.

Comment: @Exterior I've edited my answer to not mention elements.

Comment: Thank you very much. I do have a couple more questions. First, how/where do we implicitly assume the left inverse of $f$ is the projection and so on? Second - in relation to constructing the inverses, could you shed some light on how to prove $\operatorname{Ker}\ell \cong C$ [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169217/are-split-exact-sequences-exact-in-the-opposite-direction)?

Comment: @Exterior This is the statement of the [splitting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma). It says that a short exact sequence is split iff it is isomorphic to $0 \to A \to A \oplus C \to C \to 0$ *with the canonical injections and surjections*. It may be a problem of terminology, though: when I say a sequence is split, it's either left split or right split, and then the other inverse is constructed from the first. If you assume that you are given two unrelated left/right inverses, then the statement may not necessarily be true (as you saw, we really need [continued]

Comment: [continued] $r \circ s = 0$ for the complex to be contractible with this homotopy $s_\bullet$. Otherwise $s_\bullet$ is not even a chain homotopy. It's the same in the other question, if you start from a section and a retraction that are unrelated, you may not necessarily get a S.E.S., but if you start from one and construct the other from the first, it will work. This is also related to what you said in your question: "we can (and **must**) take **the** [left/right inverse]": right inverses (sections) and left inverses (retractions) are not unique.

Comment: That clarifies things. So really, the proof you supplied shows exactly why you need $r\circ s=0$, but it could essentially be "avoided" by simply quoting the splitting lemma and using the fact $\pi _2 \circ \iota _1=0$ for biproducts?

Comment: Yes, @Exterior, exactly. Essentially you want to prove that $(a,c) = (a,0) + (0,c)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23220/discussion-between-exterior-and-najib-idrissi).